# How streaming sites show video details on the browser

Tags: html, jquery, video, nav

[image]

In chrome, there is a tab beside the extensions to see the videos playing. it only appears when you play a song or video in the browser. when starting a video on youtube, I can see in that tab a background image and the title of the video and the name of the channel are already on Spotify, I can also see an image, the title of the song and the name of the artist, however, I still haven't found the medium with which they do this, for sure it is with javascript, because I searched the code of two sites mentioned and there is no  or  tag there and on my site with these tags only the page title appears on that tab.

I saw in the MDN documentation a single quote from Rich Media, but they do not go into details, they just say that it offers support and it is not what I want, it seems that this is to display ads, after all, searching on google what I discovered about it was a YouTube API to incorporate videos and tutorials talking about how to show subtitles for youtube videos, that's not what i want, i want to show the video data on this tab, at least replace the page title with the video title.

[image]

What is needed to show how in the image above?

```
<video controls>
  <source src="/msun.mp3" type="audio/mp3">
    <track label="English" kind="subtitles" srclang="en" default>

Your browser does not support the audio element.
</video>
```

Comment: Show html and css code.

Comment: @ jqueryHtmlCSS This is a browser feature, I'm not asking for codes, I want to know how it's done there and why it doesn't work with <video> https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/9692215?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They use the [MediaSession API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Media_Session_API).

Code example from linked MDN article:

```js
if ('mediaSession' in navigator) {
  navigator.mediaSession.metadata = new MediaMetadata({
    title: 'Unforgettable',
    artist: 'Nat King Cole',
    album: 'The Ultimate Collection (Remastered)',
    artwork: [
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/96x96',   sizes: '96x96',   type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/128x128', sizes: '128x128', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/192x192', sizes: '192x192', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/256x256', sizes: '256x256', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/384x384', sizes: '384x384', type: 'image/png' },
      { src: 'https://dummyimage.com/512x512', sizes: '512x512', type: 'image/png' },
    ]
  });

  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('play', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('pause', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('stop', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekbackward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekforward', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('seekto', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('previoustrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('nexttrack', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
  navigator.mediaSession.setActionHandler('skipad', function() { /* Code excerpted. */ });
}
```

Comment: Perfect! this works very well, it should have a simpler name, as I would imagine something like "MediaSession", I was thinking about structured data similar to schema.org to create that rich card.